# pthread_join() causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads, coredump, pthread-join

I'm working on understanding threads and have run up against this segmentation fault that I can't seem to correct.  I have narrowed down the error to the `pthread_join()` function, but can't seem to go any further.  My understanding is that the for loop needs to be the same as the one for the `pthread_create()` and that the variable that is passed in is the dereferenced pointer being passed into the `pthread_exit()` function. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//void *runner(void *param);

void *pFactor(void *param)
{
        int *pFArray = malloc(sizeof(int) *32);
        int myNum = atoi(param);
        int count = 0;

        printf("I'm getting here");

        while (myNum % 2 == 0)
        {
                pFArray[count] = 2;
                myNum = myNum/2;
                count++;
        }

        for (int i = 3; i < sqrt(myNum); i += 2)
        {
                while (myNum % i == 0)
                {
                        pFArray[count] = i;
                        myNum = myNum/i;
                        count++;
                }
        }

        if (myNum > 2)
        {
                pFArray[count] = myNum;
        }

        //int *arrPtr = (int*) malloc(10);
        //arrPtr = pFArray;
        //return (void *) arrPtr;
        //return fprint("I made it to the end of the pFactor function")
        pthread_exit(pFArray);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        pthread_t tid[argc];
        pthread_attr_t attr;

        if (argc == 0)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
                return -1;
        }
        if (argc < 0)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d must be >= 0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
                return -1;
        }

        /* Get the default attributes */
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        /* Create the thread */
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
                tid[i] = i;
                pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, pFactor, &argv[i]);
                printf("still working\n");
        }
        printf("still working\n");
        /* Wait for the thread to exit */
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
                tid[i] = i;
                void *my_Ptr;
                printf("still working 1\n");
                pthread_join(tid[i], &my_Ptr);
                printf("still working 2\n");
                for (;;)
                {
                        printf("%d", atoi(argv[i]));
                        printf(": %d",((int*) my_Ptr)[i-1]);
                }
                //printf("%d", atoi(argv[i]));
                //printf(": %d",((int*) my_Ptr)[i-1]);
        } /*This is where you want to pass in the sum variable*/
}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning to `tid[i]`?  In either loop?  `pthread_create()` fills in the appropriate value, and those are the values you must later pass to `pthread_join()`.

Answer (score 2):

Running your program under `valgrind` confirms your diagnosis that the issue occurs when you call `pthread_join`.  That could also be determined by running it in a debugger, but Valgrind is often especially helpful with segfaults, because its memory-use analysis often helps identify the cause of the problem, too.

In this case, however, the primary issue is clear: you call `pthread_join()` with an invalid first argument.  You seem to have a bit of a misunderstanding:

> My understanding is that the for loop needs to be the same as the one
>   for the `pthread_create()`

No, not necessarily.  The only significant association with `pthread_create` is that the first argument, a thread ID, needs to be a value that was stored by `pthread_create()`, identifying a thread that has neither been detached nor already joined.  It may be appropriate to perform your joins in a loop *similar to* the one in which you launch the threads, but that's driven by your application's particular requirements.  Typically, though, those requirements include that all the worker threads complete before the main thread proceeds past some point, and to achieve that, each one must be joined.

> and that the variable that is passed in is
>   the dereferenced pointer being passed into the pthread_exit()
>   function.

Knowing as I do what the behavior of `pthread_join()` is, I can just about squeeze those words into a shape that fits.  Myself, I would say something more like, "The second argument, if non-null, is a pointer to a location in which to write the thread function's return value, or the value it passed to `pthread_exit()`."

Anyway, the main problem is what I already expressed in comments: in your join loop, you are overwriting the thread IDs provided by `pthread_create`, and passing your arbitrary values to `pthread_join`.  **These do not identify your threads**, and in the event that your pthreads implementation is like mine, the bad thread IDs end up in fact being invalid pointers.  What you seem not to appreciate is that it is `pthread_create` that generates and assigns thread IDs.  That's why you have to pass it an address in which to store the ID.  As a corollary, it is not useful to initialize the thread ID variable before passing its address to `pthread_create`.

---

Cleaning up that issue and running your program under valgrind again reveals that you have an additional issue in your thread function, as also referenced in your other answer.  This is happening in part because your fourth argument to `pthread_create` is mismatched with your thread function's usage of its argument.

The fourth argument to `pthread_create` is passed straight through to the thread function.  You are passing `&argv[i]`, which is the address of a `char *`, a.k.a. a `char **`, automatically converted to a `void *`.  Your thread function passes its argument directly to `atoi()`, with an automatic conversion to type `char *`.  Note well that `char *` != `char **`.  I think you want the fourth argument to `pthread_create` to be simply `argv[i]`.  At least that has a type matching your use.

---

Having made *that* correction, too, I find that your program ends up in the infinite loop inside your `pthread_join` loop.  I'm not sure why you're looping there -- it appears wholly gratuitous.

Answer (score 0):

You code has an out-of-bounds write bug. [A live test of your code](https://segfault.stensal.com/a/8RB7j38J6PaKwlIH)

The following is the error message.

== Start of Stensal DTS message == copy start here ==(56.127)==

Runtime error: **[out-of-bounds write]**
  Continuing execution can cause undefined behavior, abort!

```
-
- Writing 4 bytes to 0x8fa0090 will corrupt the adjacent data.
- 
- The object to-be-written (start:0x8fa0010, size:128 bytes) is allocated at
-     file:/prog.c::10, 24
- 
-  0x8fa0010               0x8fa008f
-  +------------------------+
-  |the object to-be-written|......
-  +------------------------+
-                            ^~~~~~~~~~
-        the write starts at 0x8fa0090 that is right after the object end.
- 
- Stack trace (most recent call first) of the write.
- [1]  file:/prog.c::18, 17
- [2]  file:/musl-1.1.10/src/thread/pthread_create.c::168, 17
-
```

=== End of Stensal DTS message ==== copy end here ============